# синтаксические ошибки в шаблоне письма contact-form-7

Tags: wordpress, email, форма, плагин

На сайте `wordpress` установлен самый известный плагин `Contact Form 7`, и тот, и другой последних версий. В адмике пишет про синтаксические ошибки в конфигурации - показывает на строку с шаблоном письма **От кого**:

```
[name] <[text-email]>
```

в шаблоне формы указаны строки:

```
<p>Ф.И.О. участника<br />
[text name]</p>
<p>E-mail<br />
[text email]</p>
```

замена [name] на [text name] не помогает..

Comment: вроде помогало вместо <br /> вставлять <br> без слеша

Comment: @alenkins синтаксическая ошибка в первой части `[name] <[text-email]>`

Comment: а почему у вас `[text-email]` заключён в символы `<>`?

Comment: @alenkins нуу, обычно принято адресата  указывать вида `<mail@mail.ru>`

Comment: а плагин в курсе?)) имхо, ошибка у вас из-за этого валится

Comment: @alenkins в курсе) ошибка после этого не исчезает

Comment: тогда старый дедовский метод: убрать вообще всё и добавлять элементы по одному. Следить, когда ошибка появится. Если появляется даже в пустой форме или с единственным элементом, значит, проблема в плагине или его совместимости с текущей версией вордпресса. Либо конфликт с другими установленными плагинами